# ASP .NET code for converting a shape file to kmz file

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, shapes, kmz

Is there any ASP .NET code for converting a shape file to kmz file. Please give me a solution for this. I have searched a lot. But didnt find any solution.
Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# project for conversion to KML that may be useful as a starting point.
http://www.reimers.dk/files/esri-shapefile-to-kml

More details: http://www.reimers.dk/jacob-reimers-blog/esri-shapefile-to-kml-converter

You should be able to use .NET's System.IO.Compression API to turn the resulting KML into a KMZ.
KMZ format details:

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/394726/Converting-kml-to-kmz